# Views multiple entities output

Tags: 7, views, entities, users

*I am new to Drupal 7, so I hope I am using the word **entity** in the right context.*

I am using the profile2 module to collect additional information when yours signup. Of course, the users are required to provide an email address and they can also upload a photo of themselves.

My issue is how to use the same view to return a users user information (email, username, photo) and all the profile2 collected information.

Comment: have you tried the ```profile2_page``` module? It's a part of the profile2 module.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a view for users or the profile nodes, you should be able to add a relation to the other one. Not shure thou whether this works in both directions.